# Initialize EF Core DbContext connection with DbConnection

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-core

I am migrating EF6 .net fwk application to Entity Framework Core 3.0. however, in my old EF6 project i had an option to initialize DbContext using a DbConnection Object, was used for implementing unit of work and use same transaction without changing the connection object.

```
public MyDataContext(IDbConnection connection)
        : base((DbConnection) connection, false)
    {
    }
```

however, in EF core i have only one option to initialize the context that with a DbContextOptions, that takes a connection string. and this will initialize new connection , and I wont be able to work with transaction.

OLD EF code

```
var pipeline = endpointConfiguration.Pipeline;
        pipeline.Register(new UnitOfWorkSetupBehavior(storageSession =>
        {
            var dbConnection = storageSession.SqlPersistenceSession().Connection;
            var context = ***new MyDataContext(dbConnection);***
            context.Database.UseTransaction(storageSession.SqlPersistenceSession().Transaction);
            storageSession.SqlPersistenceSession().OnSaveChanges(x => context.SaveChangesAsync());

            return context;
        }), "Setting up unit of work");
```

Whats the alternative for the constructor with connection object, or what really changed in the EF core DBcontext not to take the connection ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In .Net core, [Dependency injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1) became a corner stone in the framework, so, now you shouldn't be initializing the DBContext yourself, you instead should [leave it to the container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext), which by default initialize it with a "[scoped liftime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1#service-lifetimes)", thus throughout one request, it'll be passing the same DbContext to your services and thus a single failure should (if you're doing it right, call the save changes only once at the very end) rollback all the changes.